# Plotly.js color palette exclude white tones

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to exclude white colors(tones) in plotly.js for a large number of bars?

For example, if i have a bar graph with 1000 bars, the default color palette will be cycle through some white colors, and those bars will be impossible to see on the white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plotly.js, you can pass an array `[1, 2, ... , 1000]` to `color` and use a built-in `colorscale` that doesn't include white. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/merillium/pen/VwbjJxE).

```
function rand() {
  return Math.random();
}

/* 
create an array of random numbers
*/
var trace1 = {
  x: Array.from({length: 1000}, (_, i) => i + 1),
  y: Array.from({length: 1000}, (_, i) => i + 1).map(rand),
  type: 'bar',
  marker: {
    color: Array.from({length: 1000}, (_, i) => i + 1),
    colorscale: "Viridis"
  }
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Non-white Bars with colorscale',
  font:{
    family: 'Raleway, sans-serif'
  },
  showlegend: false,
  xaxis: {
    tickangle: -45
  },
  yaxis: {
    zeroline: false,
    gridwidth: 2
  },
  bargap :0.05
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

[image]